# How to perform a method over selected blocks of lines in Python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I have a log file with around 1000 lines. In that I would like to perform a function over selected blocks of lines. Say from lines [1 to 100], [200 to 400] and [600-900]. Ignore the rest.

The log file looks like below:

```
Something here...  
... ... ...   
Start                      # BLOCK 1 begins 
a b c d e f g  
h i j k l m n  
End                        # BLOCK 1 ends
something here...  
Start                      # BLOCK 2 begins 
a b c d e f g  
h i j k l m n  
End                        # BLOCK 2 ends
something here... 
Start                      # BLOCK 3 begins 
a b c d e f g  
h i j k l m n  
End                        # BLOCK 3 ends
something here... 
... ... ...
```

I have the following Python program to perform the method (some_method)over the whole log. The regex retrieves the last occurrences of lines which contain "Start" and "End" in them(currently only for Block 3). However, I need something that performs the function separately for each block between the lines "Start" and "End"

```
    def reader(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                log = f.read()
                regex_PTT = ".*Start"
        
                list_PTT = []
                list_PTT.append(re.findall(regex_PTT, log)[-1])
                print list_PTT
        
                regex_playString = ".*End"
                list_Play = []
                list_Play.append(re.findall(regex_playString, log)[-1])
                print list_Play
                return some_method(ts_PTT, ts_playString) # this is the function performed between beginning of Block 3 and ending of Block 3 presently
 
def some_method(ts_PTT, ts_playString):
      # do something 
 
    if __name__ == '__main__': # main function
        response_timestamp = reader('log') 
        print 'Latency: ', response_timestamp
```

How can I make this program run 3 or more times separately over each block(between consecutive "Start" and "End" line) without consuming too much time.

Eg., 2. Please suggest a solution for similar case of text file given below where there is no end delimiter:

```
Something here...  
... ... ...   
Line that contains .*EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen=HMI_ACTIVE_NONE;         # BLOCK 1 begins 
a b c d e f g  
h i j k l m n  
something here...  
Line that contains .*EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen=HMI_ACTIVE_NONE;         # BLOCK 2 begins 
a b c d e f g  
h i j k l m n  
something here...
```

I would like to know if a WHILE loop could be used such that the method could be executed until the next occurence of the line that contains "EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen=HMI_ACTIVE_NONE"

**SOLUTION:** :

```
def log_reader(filename, sessionType):
    with open(filename) as f:
        log = f.read()
        if sessionType.lower() == 'wuw':
            block_regex = "PREPARING => STARTING_RECOGNITION[\w\W]*?Scheduled event after flush: N"
        else:
            block_regex = "EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen[\w\W]*?Scheduled event after flush: N"

        regex_PTT = ".*beginSpeechFrame"
        regex_playString = "(.*nuance_prompter_IPrompter_playString IPrompter_instance='SDS_prompter' " \
                           "IPrompt_instance='IPrompt_)(?!.*wav.*)"
        ts_PTT_list = []
        ts_playString_list = []
        result = re.findall(block_regex, log)
        for block in result:
##do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to create a list with the contents of each block:

```
import re

blocks = re.split(r"Start.*|End.*", log)[1:-1]
```

The `[1:-1]` assumes that `Start` is not on the very first line of the file and `End` is not on the last line.

Then you can loop through that list and do whatever you like with it.

**EDIT:**

If there is only one delimiter as shown in the edited question, you can use:

```
re.split(r".*EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen=HMI_ACTIVE_NONE.*", log)[1:]
```

It's not entirely clear how your data is set up, so you may only want `[1:]` in this case instead of `[1:-1]`.

Comment: Hi jdaz, thank you for the response. This will work now if "Start" and "End" are the delimiters. In my case what if that is also a line consisting of a pattern. I want to slice the file amongst 2 regex patterns. Please see the description for 2nd case. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can just use `firstPattern|secondPattern` instead of `Start.*|End.*`.

Comment: What if there is not any end delimiter. Please see my updated description. I would like to know if a WHILE loop could be used such that the method could be executed until the next occurrence of the line that contains "EVNT GDM NAME=PTT hmi_active_screen=HMI_ACTIVE_NONE"

Comment: Ok I've added to my answer, if I'm understanding this new question correctly

Comment: Hi, your case didn't work for me because Start wasn't the beginning part of my line. So I used the following line. I've also added my solution program to my question. `block_regex = "PREPARING => STARTING_RECOGNITION[\w\W]*?Scheduled event after flush: N"`